# highlight certain text in pdf ios sdk

Tags: ios, pdf

I am using pdf reader sample for display pdf and book marking.
But i need some extra features i.e  highlight certain text in pdf and want to make it saved.
using ios sdk.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: This has been asked and answered many many times... Please try searching for answers before you post a new question

Comment: thank you for your replay,and i have searched google for 2 days and i found  lot of paid sdks and i coundn't find any free sdks , i don't want that paid sdks,is there any code which supports highliting text in pdf? if you know how to do that please let me.

Comment: https://github.com/KurtCode/PDFKitten